# $\sum_{k=1}^{180^\circ}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{k}\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How to compute $$\sum_{k=1}^{180}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{k}\right)$$

I have tried several ways to do it (including euler formula, etc), but all failed. The answer given by wolframalpha appeared to be a bad irrational number...

**Edited:** The source of the problem is a test from our school. Maybe there is a typo on the upper bound $180$. How if the problem changes to $\sum_{k=1}^{180^\circ}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{k}\right)$? Is there a chance to have a closed form?

Comment: What makes you think there is a closed form?

Comment: What's the source of this problem? The summand and range for index both look strange.

Comment: Pity it's not something like $\cos(2\pi k/180)$. Anyway, here's your sum to 100 places, computed using mpmath: 171.4640044505613428214098838495749812772666106357843039716361604645700754843936911252650831636893844

Comment: Strange. The $2\pi$ suggests we're working in radians, but the $180$ suggests we're working in degrees.

Comment: I mean, you can loosely approximate if you like. Just write down all the cos values you know first, and then approximate other terms with $k\ge 5$ as $1$. I get $174.07$ which is not bad.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Editted!

Comment: We will all be interested in seeing the solution your teacher gives to this test question. I hope you will post it here, or ask your teacher to post it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{180}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{k}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{6}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{k}\right)+\sum_{k=7}^{180}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{k}\right)$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{6}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{k}\right)=\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{5}-1\right)$$

Now, using Taylor series
$$\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{k}\right)=1-\frac{2 \pi ^2}{k^2}+\frac{2 \pi ^4}{3 k^4}-\frac{4 \pi ^6}{45 k^6}+\frac{2 \pi
   ^8}{315 k^8}-\frac{4 \pi ^{10}}{14175 k^{10}}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^{12}}\right)$$ You then have a long analytical formula and, numerically

$$\sum_{k=1}^{180}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{k}\right)=171.4640044498\cdots$$ while the exact value is $171.4640044506\cdots$